# Why are the contents of /dev/shm/ is being removed automatically

Tags: linux, ssh

On a RHEL 7.2 machine, if I create a POSIX shared memory in a console session, then query its presence in `/dev/shm` from an SSH session, it shows the shared memory file during the first time, but after that it gets deleted mysteriously.

Finally I've broken down the test case to the following steps:

1. On box1, do `touch /dev/shm/sample`
2. `tailf /dev/shm/sample` on box1. It will be accessible.
3. On box2, do `ssh user@box1 "ls -l /dev/shm/"`

   ```
   -rw------- 1 user user        1 Aug 25 17:12 sample
   ```
4. Do step 3 again, and this time I don't see the file.
5. On box1, tailf shows that the file has been deleted.

   ```
   tail: '/dev/shm/sample' has become inaccessible: No such file or directory
   ```

I've observed is that all the files corresponding to that particular user are getting deleted from `/dev/shm`, even if that is a tree of directories, containing files.

I've tried to monitor the file, strace on sshd, etc.

I have tried auditd with the following rules, but no luck:

```
## This file is automatically generated from /etc/audit/rules.d
-D
-b 1024
# monitor unlink() and rmdir() system calls.
-a exit,always -S unlink -S rmdir
```

Can someone explain what is going wrong here?

Comment: The way you phrase it gives me the impression it's related to the user so I'm curious if you tried it with a different user.

Comment: Only one user is affected, did you see other-user files still present while affected-user ones gets deleted? If this is a powerful user, have you checked its crontabs (in case it created a custom cleanup entry)

Comment: Yes, the other user files, for eg, gdm's pulse-shm-* are still present while the files are removed. The crontabs are empty. I have root access to this box and I've made sure it is clean.

Comment: It looks suspiciously like the end of the SSH session is performing some misguided "clean up" of user files in `/dev/shm`.  Try an interactive SSH session (or `ssh box1 sleep 20`) and narrow down when the file is removed.

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Ubuntu 16.04: http://askubuntu.com/questions/884127/16-04-lts-and-dev-shm-garbage-collection

Answer (score 26, accepted):

[From my answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/884449/196339):

> After hours of searching and reading, I found the culprit. It's a
>   setting for [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/). The `/etc/systemd/logind.conf` contains
>   default configuration options, with each of them commented out. The
>   `RemoveIPC` option is set to `yes` by default. That option tells
>   `systemd` to clean up interprocess communication (IPC) for "user
>   accounts" who aren't logged in. This does not affect "system accounts"
>
> In my case, the files and directories were being created for a user
>   account, not a system account.
>
> There are two possible solutions:
>
> 1. Create the files with/for a system user -- a user created with the system option (`adduser -r` or `adduser --system`)
> 2. Edit `/etc/systemd/logind.conf`, uncomment the line `RemoveIPC=yes`, change it to `RemoveIPC=no`, save, and reboot the
>      system
>
> In my case, I went with option #2 because the user was already
>   created.
>
> **References:**
>
> - [RemoveIPC prematurely removes IPC segments](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/4532)
> - [Change default value of RemoveIPC in logind.conf](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/2039)
> - PostgreSQL: [Systemd](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Systemd)
> - Oracle: [3.5 Database Installation and Operation Fails if RemoveIPC=yes Is Configured for systemd](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E52668_01/E67200/html/section-t51_kcn_f5.html)

Comment: Is there a way to convert the existing user to a 'system' user? Not sure if this has to have it's own question though.

Comment: @Arun - A system user is denoted by the ID that's assigned when it's created. There are system defined ranges for regular users and system accounts. I don't know if it's possible to change the user ID to put it in the correct range, or if it's feasible to edit the ranges. http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80279/68071

Comment: @Arun - Looks like it's possible to change the user ID, but there are caveats: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18248169/244826

Comment: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/howto-change-rename-user-name-id/

Comment: Only requires a restart `systemctl restart systemd-logind`.

Comment: Thanks, this helped a lot in our system where I am using Boost :: Interprocess!

Answer (score 1):

`/dev/shm` provides a view of the shared memory that appears like a file system.  There are system calls to create, use, and delete shared memory segments.  Shared memory is intended to be used by co-operating programs to allow access to shared data structures.  Depending on the mode they were created with, shared memory segments may be removed when no processes are using them.  This prevents shared memory from being lost if the programs using them crash or otherwise exit without cleaning up.

If you have a kernel that mounts `/dev/shm`, then it should be listed as such in `/etc/mtab`.  The permissions should be `drwxrwxrwxt` which prevents other users other than root from removing the files.  If files for a particular user are being removed from `/dev/shm` it will be either that user or root that is removing them.  Check for: processes running as the user; cronjobs running as the user; or scripts run a during login/logout.

Try logging in several times without logging out and checking for the file.  If the file sticks around, then it is unlikely a process running as the user or a crontab entry.  If it is deleted on the first logout, then it is likely a cleanup script run on logout.

If you want to create a file system in memory, there is the `tmpfs` file system.   This is commonly used for `/tmp`, `/var/run` and other file systems that should be empty following a reboot.  Files in `tmpfs` may be paged out to the swap files if memory is used for other purposes.

Comment: You are right about where standard temp files should be stored (I do not think it is the usage of @Arun). But I think you are wrong with `/dev/shm`. I do think that: `/dev/shm/` is a pure `tmpfs` mount (often auto-mounted by boot scripts without the need of any fstab entry). It used to contain standard files created by POSIX SHM userland implementation, which content is then `mmap`ed to any process using it, and named posix shm files can be deleted when last process detaches from them thanks to posix shm userland implementation (I still guess).